# python array slicing behaviour with negative stepsizes and omitting / None values for start & stop

Tags: python-3.x, slice

I have an array as shown
`marks = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8]`
I would like to understand the different between the following notations

`marks[::-2]`, `marks[None:None:-2]` and `marks[0:len(marks):-2]`

I know there have been some attempts to answer the same question , But am not understanding those.

What i could gather from the other responses is that when the indices are omitted ,  **start** would default to **0** , **end** would default to **len(marks)** and **step size** would default to **1** .

Also omission of indices and giving `None` would yield same behavior . But i never observed it , especially in the above cases . For example if the above statement is true then

`marks[::-2]` =  `marks[0:len(marks):-2]` which should give an empty list because you can never start from 0 index and reach an index len(marks) - 1 taking a negative step size of 2 but instead  `marks[::-2]` is giving me `[8, 6, 3, 1]` what is the mechanism behind this ? Also please explain what **None** really means in this context

**Edit**

Below is the answer to the question which was mentioned as a comment in one of the answers given to a similar question although the answer wasn't accepted

`maxint = 10000000 if step is None: step = 1 elif step == 0: raise ValueError('slice step cannot be zero') if start is None: start = maxint if step < 0 else 0 if stop is None: stop = -maxint if step < 0 else maxint`

Comment: I don't think you can get a better explanation than answers to this question. [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Comment: The first answer in that link which you gave really didn't address my question to the point unless i overlooked something , but there was a part 2 answer to the same question (although not accepted) over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top , please refer below code snippet which kind of answers what exactly is going on

Comment: maxint = 10000000
    if step is None:
        step = 1
    elif step == 0:
        raise ValueError('slice step cannot be zero')
    if start is None:
        start = maxint if step < 0 else 0
    if stop is None:
        stop = -maxint if step < 0 else maxint

Comment: Can you edit this code into the question? and raise a reopen flag?

Comment: @mx0 - I have edited and clicked on Reopen

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24713353/446792) deals with negative steps.
For negative steps defaults are: `start = -1, stop = -len(string) - 1`